# Python Pandas : group by in group by and rolling average of the last value from the first groupby?

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby, apply, rolling-computation

I know the title is confusing, but the question is also confusing :)

I have dataframe looking like:

```
Date            Period       Warehose       Value
10-01-1998      Jan-1998     London          10
13-01-1998      Jan-1998     London          13
15-01-1998      Dec-1997     London          37
...
07-01-1998      Jan-1998     New York        20
15-01-1998      Jan-1998     New York        37
21-01-1998      Nov-1997     New York        17
```

- Date denotes when the entry was made
- Period denotes the period for which the entry was made
- Value denotes the end of month inventory

I'm trying to buil a function which would give me for every date the average end of month inventory of the last year for the particular warehouse. However, since some months the inventory data becomes available later on, I cannot use future observation for the calculation.

I've been thinking of some kinky combination of .groupby, .rolling('1Y').mean(), .apply() but nothing has worked.

I first do df.groupby('Warehouse') but then I have to groupby('period').date.max() which is before the date of observation and then take the rolling mean.

Do you have ideas on how to solve this efficiently? Data is about 1 million rows...

EDIT: Expected output. Hope it makes it more clear. Basically each date update just update the value of the period it refers to from the 1 year average.

```
Date        Warehose    **1-Year Average**
10-01-1998   London  (10 + sum(End Month Values Dec-1997.. Jan-1997))/count
13-01-1998   London  (13 + sum(End Month Values Dec-1997.. Jan-1997))/count
15-01-1998   London  (13 + 37 + sum(End Month Values... Jan-1997))/count
...
07-01-1998  New York (20 + sum(End Month Values Dec-1997.. Jan-1997))/count
15-01-1998  New York (37 + sum(End Month Values Dec-1997.. Jan-1997))/count
21-01-1998  New York (37 + Dec-1997 + 17 + Oct-1997.. + Jan-1997))/count
```

EDIT2: Maybe the explanation above wasn't very good. I'll try in another way:

I have data for each month (Period) but sometimes it gets revised few months later because it has been wrong. Each date of the revision is in column 'Date'. I'm trying to get the average of the last 12 periods per warehouse but using only the last update (correct) value for each month.

The thing is, I cannot use the very last/correct value per period because it would be lookahead bias. I have to use only the updates that occured before each Date

Comment: Hi flT, for tricky questions like this, it would be helpful if you could provide an "expected result" given your dummy data. It is much easier to follow your situation visually than by assumption. I like to do a DF with 10 rows that can encompass all of my weird situations. In fact many times during setting up an MCVE I have arrived at the solution on my own. Thanks!

Comment: Hope this makes it somehow more understandable

Comment: Question is similar to: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33478491/take-last-value-of-the-prior-grouping-in-a-rolling-sum-function-pandas-python?rq=1
with the difference that my data is not that aligned